# General question about Galton Board

Tags: classical-mechanics, collision, probability, statistics

I’m new here, and most notably NOT a Scientist, but I do have a question about
the [Galton Board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine) (which I happily stumbled upon today, thanks to YouTube and ‘the quarantine’)

So, as I understand it, every time a falling ball encounters a peg it has a 50-50 chance of going either Left or Right - then as it makes its way downward, it has a far greater chance of occasionally doing both (instead of primarily Left, or primarily Right) and thus the majority end up in the center.  That makes perfect sense – however, that’s not exclusively what I observe when watching the balls in slow motion.  What I see is a great many of the balls (primarily in the center) interacting not only with the pegs, but the other balls as well, and thus potentially changing the initial trajectory of their routes.

So my question is, would there be any notable change in the distribution of the balls if dropped one at a time, and with no opportunity for ball to ball interaction?  If I had to guess I’d say it would be a slightly flattened curve, but I could be completely wrong.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if mathematics would be better for this, since you aren't asking about the particular interactions between the balls. But I'm not completely convinced of this thought. Certainly it's a good question that can have some interesting answers, but I'm not sure how much physics is actually involved here. I'll see what other people think.

Comment: the interaction between the balls does not have a preference for left or right either, so subtracting it out would not change the distribution. in fact, it would be a better analogy of the central limit theorem, since we consider independent events there anyway.

Comment: removal of the collisions among the balls is going to provide you with an experiment which strongly represents the central limit theorem as the balls have only the binomial way of choosing left or right than forced by some other balls.